# How to automate the configuration of LDAP and other plugins for Jenkins using ansible or some other tool

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I am working on a project where I need to automate the LDAP and other plugin configuration without manual intervention .Is this possible using Ansible?Or can experts some one suggest a better way to do it.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended approach for configuring plugins is [JCasC](https://jenkins.io/projects/jcasc). You must inatall the [JCasC plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/configuration-as-code/). [LDAP plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ldap) supports JCasC.

Note: JCasC does not manage the installation of plugins themselves, [that's a separate topic](https://jenkins.io/projects/gsoc/2019/plugin-installation-manager-tool-cli), just the configuration.